# Replacing text in multiple files with text from a list in order

Tags: command-line, sed, text-processing

Let's say I have the following files:

```
/etc/dir1/file.txt
/etc/dir2/file.txt
/etc/dir3/file.txt
```

... all the way up to `dir100` (100 directories), every directory has `file.txt`.

And I have the following text file in `/root/list.txt`. In `list.txt`, I have 100 lines, each line with a different string of text.

In each `file.txt`, there is the string of text, `word1`.

How would I use `sed` (or something similar) to replace the word `word1` in every `file.txt`, with one line from `list.txt`? Each line in `list.txt`, is only to be used once.

So for example, replace `word1` in `/etc/dir1/file.txt` with the first line in `/root/list.txt`, and replace `word1` `/etc/dir2/file.txt` with the second line in `/root/list.txt` and so on, all the way up to 100.

I greatly appreciate any help and assistance here as `sed` is not my strong point.

Answer (score 3):

#### You can do this with `sed` in a loop *if* the lines of `list.txt` are well-behaved.

> How would I use `sed` (or something similar) to replace the word
>   `word1` in every `file.txt`, with one line from `list.txt`? Each line
>   in `list.txt`, is only to be used once.

Ubuntu has [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), which [**makes it easy**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33416489/1038860) to replace only the first occurrence of a pattern in a file, then stop. To use separate replacement strings for each input file, you can use a loop. The code below is *just* complex enough that I suggest making it a script and running the script. There are three major caveats:

1. The pattern `word1`--which I presume you may  change to something else--must not contain `/`, unless you use a different delimiter in the `sed` command. Nor may it contain characters `sed` treats specially, such as regular expression metacharacters (`\`, `*`, `.`, and so forth), unless that's what you intend.
2. **The lines in `list.txt` must not contain `/` or most special characters either.**
3. Your `dir1`, `dir2`, ..., are in `/etc` and your `list.txt` is in `/root`, but I've written my script to assume those directories--and that file--are in the *current directory* instead. I did this because files stored in those locations are often important, and I assume you will want to test this script--and perhaps make your own modifications--before using it for real. You can change the script to use the locations you gave, or any other locations you need.

I've bolded #2 becuase it's the one I expect might cause you trouble, depending on what `list.txt` might contain. Now that you've been warned, here's the script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

mapfile -t <list.txt

for ((i=1; i<=${#MAPFILE[@]}; ++i))
do sed -i.bak "0,/word1/ s//${MAPFILE[i-1]}/" "dir$i/file.txt"
done
```

That's all it takes. In case you're interested, here's how it works:

- `mapfile` is [a Bash builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins) that reads lines into [an array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays). I use it [to read from](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections) `list.txt`. I didn't specify the array's name so the default name of `MAPFILE` is used.
- Bash offers [an alternate (C-style) `for` loop](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Looping-Constructs), which [is useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/171041/1038860) when one wants to loop from or to a value obtained by [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), since [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) in Bash won't expand things like `{1..$var}`. I use it to loop from 1 to the length of the `MAPFILE` array.
- `sed -i` replaces the original file. **You lose the old version unless you provide a backup suffix.** You can remove `.bak` from the command if you don't want to keep the old version but I recommend you consider keeping it. Please at least test with it before removing it.
- [With GNU sed, `0,/word1/ s//REPLACEMENT/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33416489/1038860) operates only in the range from the beginning of the file to the first match with `word1` (`0,/word1/`), replacing text matching that same pattern with *`REPLACEMENT`* (`s//*REPLACEMENT*/`). This is to say that it replaces only the first match in the input. The rest of the input is unchanged regardless of whether it would match the pattern.
- Bash arrays are indexed starting with `0`, but your files are named starting from `1`, which is where I decided the loop variable `$i` should start. Fortunately this is easy to deal with because Bash arrays accept arithmetic expressions as indices. `${MAPFILE[i-1]}` expands to element **i - 1** (that is, the **i**<sup>th</sup> element) of the array of lines from `list.txt`.

---

#### To replace using *arbitrary* text read from a file, consider alternatives to `sed`.

If you can't abide caveat #2--that is, the lines in `list.txt` could be just about anything--then I don't know of a good way to do this with `sed`. But there are a number of alternatives. Bash can actually do this itself, without any external commands, and I'll show an almost pure-Bash solution. (Perhaps more answers will be posted to show methods using [`awk`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/gawk.1.html) or other utilities.)

In `sed`, a pattern is a regular expressio. But ***this* method treats the pattern [as a glob](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion)**. See also [this FOLDOC entry](https://foldoc.org/glob) and [`man 7 glob`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man7/glob.7.html). Thus special characters including `*`, `?`, `[`, and `]`--and some others like `\`--have special meanings in `word1` (just not usually the same meanings as in `sed`). If `word1` is literally `word1` or any other text with no globbing characters, no problem. Otherwise you must modify it accordingly. **This method removes caveat #2 but *not* caveat #1**--nor #3, but you can deal with that yourself easily.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

pattern='word1' # text to search for
suffix='.bak'   # suffix to append for backup files

mapfile -t <list.txt

for ((i=1; i<=${#MAPFILE[@]}; ++i)); do
    name="dir$i/file.txt"
    mv "$name" "$name$suffix" || exit  # quit with an error if we can't rename

    {
        while read -r; do  # output up to and including the replacement
            case "$REPLY" in
            *"$pattern"*)
                printf '%s\n' "${REPLY/$pattern/${MAPFILE[i-1]}}"
                break ;;
            *)
                printf '%s\n' "$REPLY" ;;
            esac
        done

        while read -r; do  # output the rest
            printf '%s\n' "$REPLY"
        done

    } <"$name$suffix" >"$name"
done
```

In case you're (still) interested, here's how *that* works:

- As before, I read `list.txt` into an array. I could also read each `file.txt` into an array, but for all I know these files could be enormous, so I'm reading them one line at a time with `read -r` instead.
- I move each file aside by renaming it with a `.bak` suffix with [`mv`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/mv.1.html). `mv` is the only external utility this script uses. I haven't bothered to pass `--` before the path because, in this case, there's no way the path can start with `-`. If the move operation fails, `mv` will output an error and `|| exit` terminates the script, preventing accidental data loss. The only data that should be possible to lose by running this script is data in pre-existing `.bak` files.
- The two loops that read input and write output are [grouped together](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping) with `{` `}`. The whole group has both its [input](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirecting-Input) and [output](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirecting-Output) redirected to use the `.bak` file as input and a file named the same as the original as output (`<"$name$suffix" >"$name"`).
- Each loop may read many lines, and the only way `read -r` itself modifies them is to remove the [newline characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) at the ends (which [`printf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/printf.1posix.html) will put back with `\n` later). In Bash, `read -r` with no variable name reads a line to `$REPLY` and doesn't strip leading and trailing whitespace; it is equivalent to `IFS= read -r REPLY`.
- The first loop reads until a line appears consisting of any or no characters (`*`), followed by `word1` ("`$pattern`"), followed again by any or no characters (`*`). When it finds such a line it prints it but replaces the part that matches `"$pattern"` with the **i**<sup>th</sup> line from `list.txt` (`${MAPFILE[i-1]}`) and then breaks the loop. All the lines before that one are just printed verbatim.
- The second loop prints all the remaining lines verbatim.

By using two loops grouped together, I've achieved the same basic logic as the `sed` way detailed above--text up to, including, but not beyond the first match is processed first so the match is substituted, then subsequent text is not searched at all, just copied. However, unlike in that `sed` method, special characters in what `${MAPFILE[i-1]}` expands to are not treated as part of the command.

For example, observe that a replacement string that tried to cause trouble by closing the inner parameter expansion and [injecting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) additional substitutions would not succeed:

```bash
$ s=foobarbaz t=bar u='}$s$s$s'; echo "${s/$t/${u}}"
foo}$s$s$sbaz
```

Answer (score 1):

**Let's create test environment** placed in the user's `$HOME` directory.

- First execute next line as single command:

  ```
  path="${HOME}/etc/dir"; for i in {1..100}; do mkdir -p "$path$i" ; echo -e "$path$i/file.txt:\nline1 some text here\nline2 word1 some text here word1\nline3 word1 some text here" > "$path$i/file.txt"; done
  ```

  This will create hundred directories - `~/etc/dir{1..100}`. In each directory will be created also a file, called `file.txt`, that contains the string `word1` few times:

  ```
  $ cat ~/etc/dir{1..100}/file.txt
  /home/<user>/etc/dir1/file.txt:
  line1 some text here
  line2 word1 some text here word1
  line3 word1 some text here
  /home/<user>/etc/dir2 file.txt: 
  ...
  ```
- Then execute this line:

  ```
  path="${HOME}/root" && mkdir "$path"; for i in {1..100}; do echo '*{string line ['"$i"']}*' >> "$path/list.txt"; done
  ```

  This will create a directory, called `~/root`. In the directory will be created also a file, called `list.txt`, that contains hundred lines:

  ```
  $ cat ~/root/list.txt
  *{string line [1]}*
  *{string line [2]}*
  ...
  ```

**Let's solve the task**. According to the circumstances, create into the above step, because the string `word1` occurs several times, we have several cases. Example solutions:

- To replace only the first occurrence of `word1` in each `file.txt`, execute this line:

  ```
  i=""; while read line; do i=$((i+1)); sed "0,/word1/ s|\word1|${line}|1" "$HOME/etc/dir$i/file.txt"; done < "$HOME/root/list.txt"
  ```

  The output should be:

  ```
  /home/<user>/etc/dir1/file.txt:
  line1 some text here
  line2 *{string line [1]}* some text here word1
  line3 word1 some text here
  /home/<user>/etc/dir2 file.txt:
  ...
  ```
- To replace only the first occurrence of `word1` on each line in each `file.txt`, execute this line:

  ```
  i=""; while read line; do i=$((i+1)); sed "s|\word1|${line}|1" "$HOME/etc/dir$i/file.txt"; done < "$HOME/root/list.txt"
  ```

  The output should be:

  ```
  /home/<user>/etc/dir1/file.txt:
  line1 some text here
  line2 *{string line [1]}* some text here word1
  line3 *{string line [1]}* some text here
  /home/<user>/etc/dir2 file.txt:
  ...
  ```
- To replace all occurrences of `word1` in each `file.txt`, execute this line:

  ```
  i=""; while read line; do i=$((i+1)); sed "s|\word1|${line}|g" "$HOME/etc/dir$i/file.txt"; done < "$HOME/root/list.txt"
  ```

  The output should be:

  ```
  /home/<user>/etc/dir1/file.txt:
  line1 some text here
  line2 *{string line [1]}* some text here *{string line [1]}*
  line3 *{string line [1]}* some text here
  /home/<user>/etc/dir2 file.txt:
  ...
  ```

**Notes**. Into the above examples:

- Change `sed` with `sed -i` for actual replacement of the strings or use `sed -i.bak` to do the replacements and leave also a backup file.
- Remove `$HOME` according to the circumstances, described into the question.